# Regex for two letters and up to 13 digits incorrectly accepts additional letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to build a regexp for a model field that follows this rule:

- starts with two letters
- can be filled up with digits, up to 13 digits

Valid examples:

- `US333`
- `FR52389000`

Invalid examples:

- `11111`
- `T11`

I thought I found the right regex:

```
/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d*/
```

But proof testing it with http://rubular.com/ seems to validate `RR444kjj`

Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: Do you mean something like [`/\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\d{0,13}\z/`](http://rubular.com/r/1pmH5lDk7j)? Note that `[[:alpha:]]{2}` matches 2 letters and `\d{0,13}` matches 0 to 13 digits.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, is it Ruby regular ? cause it seems to fail everything in http://rubular.com/ ...

Comment: What does it fail? You might misunderstand Ruby regex anchors. `\A` is start of the string, `^` is a start of the line. `\z` is the end of the string, and `$` is the end of the line. If you test a regex against a multiline string, you need to use `^` and `$`, but when using the regex in the real Ruby environment for validation, you need to use correct anchors.

Comment: oh ok I clicked your link and it seems to work, but regexp shows `^[[:alpha:]]{2}\d{0,13}$` should i use this one ? with /A and /z it seems not to work. but with ^ and $ it works

Comment: Demo is only meant to show how it works. Only a test in the real environment is a valid proof.

Comment: @Maxence, you're right: it doesn't work with `/A` and `/z`. Try `\A` and `\z`. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a limiting quantifier with `\d` and correct anchors.

```
/\A[[:alpha:]]{2}\d{0,13}\z/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/1pmH5lDk7j).

- `\A` - start of the string (note that the `^` anchor matches the start of the line in Ruby regex)
- `[[:alpha:]]{2}` - 2 letters (to make sure you only allow ASCII letters, use `[a-zA-Z]{2}`)
- `\d{0,13}` - 0 to 13 digits
- `\z` - end of string (note that the `$` anchor matches the end of the line in Ruby regex).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I think mine failed because I forgot the start and end of string (oh and yes the 13 digits limit ^^ but i check the field length also). Thanks for your explanation

Comment: Wiktor, it's curious you used POSIX for the string and `\d` for the digits, rather than the POSIX `[[:digit:]]`. I understand why you used POSIX for the string, and that `\d` and `[[:digit:]]` are equivalent, but still, curious.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP mentions *letters*, so the first thing that came to my mind was an `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class and the `\p{L}` Unicode property/category class. It is of lesser importance here anyway, as it turned out.